# Wireless HD video stream for flight simulator

Tags: wireless, video

A high definition video is needed to be streamed out from a highly movable platform with a range of 5 meters. What do I need? both hardware and software. In the movable platform there is a PC and on the ground an LCD is preferable. The cost is important.

Explanation: The movable platform is flight simulator for gaming purposes, in which a PC is embedded. That is, in the transmitter, we have a PC with all its peripherals like USB, PCI, etc. We need to stream out the output of the game and see it on an LCD. Outside of the movable platform, we need to see the streaming video with lowest possible cost in an LCD. One way is to install a PC outside the movable platform and use a VNC to transmit the streaming video. However, it seems that implementing these requirements with lower cost is also possible.

One strict restriction:
-THE CABLE CANNOT BE USED.

Comment: Any suggestions would work

Comment: For 5 meters, it seems like the easiest thing is just to run a cable. Is there something preventing that?

Comment: yes, it is not possible to use cable. The platform can rotate in 2 axes. Therefore, the cable cannot be brought out of the platform.

Comment: I see. Do you want the monitor on the ground to be driven by the same computer, or prefer a different computer, or no preference?

Comment: The cost and visibility are important. So the preference is big LCD or LED, with as less as possible more hardware.

Comment: Doesn't quite answer what I was asking. Do you want the display that's not on the platform to be driven by the computer that's running the flight simulator, or a different computer? Basically, do you want to stream it over the network and have a different computer display the data, or use the same computer with some sort of wireless display adapter?

Comment: It is preferable to be on the same computer as flight simulator if possible. If not we may add additional hardware, with lowest possible cost

Comment: @Hamid the easiest solution is definitely to run a cable. If this platform rotates in two axes, then there is a point that always remains stationary - right at the center of the mounting. Run the cable through that point, and you won't run into any issues with the rotation.

Comment: It is not possible to use cable.